# SQLAlchemy map custom query results to a specific class

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a next ORM model class:

```
class SearchResults(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    author_id = Column(String)
    article_id = Column(String)
```

I would like to return only two columns:

- author_id
- article_id

This class presents an result of a search query it has no corresponding table.

ORM is failing with an error:

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class 'app.db.models.SearchResults'>'
```

When class is used in the SQLAlchemy query like this:

```
search_results = db.query(SearchResults).select_from(models.Article).join(models.Author).all()
```

And when columns are specified I am getting a Tuple instead of a class in the results:

```
search_results = db.query(models.Acticle.id, models.Author.author_id).select_from(models.Article).join(models.Author).all()
```

**Question: is it possible to map non-table results to a class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [Mapping a Class against Arbitrary Selects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects) or [Mapping a Class against Multiple Tables](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables) sections of the documentation.

For the second example you can get tables for `Article` and `Author` by using:

```
author_table = models.Author.__table__
article_table = modesl.Article.__table__
```